# Can I run Python code in Julia language for speed increase?

Tags: performance, julia

Ive been looking at speed comparisons of the new language Julia and have been impressed as it seems much faster than Python.  The thing is so much of the underlying code I have created as well as user-contributed modules are already in Python.  So I was wondering...Can I call Python code from Julia to get the speed increase or does it not work at all like that?

Comment: And if you'll call the python code - won't it run at... the same speed ?

Comment: I was hoping that the Julia would translate Python to Julia and run the calculations from there

Comment: "translate Python Julia" - how ? in order to "translate" one language to another you need to write a compiler...

Answer (score 4):

No it does not work like that. If you call python code in Julia, via [Pycall](https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl) for example, a python interpreter is invoked and will run the python code - thus no speed benefits of Julia would translate to the python code execution.

Even so, you could rewrite parts of your Python code that are performing too poorly in Julia, and continue to use the remaining bulk of the Python code.

Comment: I have a better idea, write a compiler from Python to Julia ;)